# How to enlarge shiny app to (browser) window size?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to fit the app which is hosted on the shiny plattform to the entire available window size.
When I run the app from within R and click on "Open in Browser" from the R popup window, it will make use of the entire browser.
But when I open it from the web url, it will be in a quite small window which is much too small:

[image]

Above you can slightly see my bookmark panel and below the taskbar.
How can I adjust the size of that app?

edit: Here's the code (at least the one I think that is meaningful in this context? The entire file is nearly 5000 lines long):

````
---
title: "CCD Analysis"
resource_files:
- app/server.R
- app/ui.R
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r, include=FALSE}
(....)
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='.....', 
                          token='......', 
                          secret='.....')

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
window_height = 550

ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Sensor qualification", titleWidth = 300),
        dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("1. Ambient temperature", tabName = "1_Effects", icon = icon("thermometer-half")),
                        menuItem("2. Humidity", tabName = "2_Effects", icon = icon("tint")),
                        menuItem("3. Detection limit", tabName = "3_Effects", icon = icon("microscope")),
                        menuItem("4. Signal noise air", tabName = "4_Effects", icon = icon("signal")),
                        menuItem("5. Signal noise gas", tabName = "5_Effects", icon = icon("signal")),
                        menuItem("6. Sensitivity", tabName = "6_Effects", icon = icon("balance-scale")),
                        menuItem("7. Cross-sensitivity", tabName = "7_Effects", icon = icon("balance-scale")),
                        menuItem("8. Linearity", tabName = "8_Effects", icon = icon("chart-line")),
                        menuItem("9. Linearizability", tabName = "9_Effects", icon = icon("chart-line")),
                        menuItem("10. Sensor response air", tabName = "10_Effects", icon = icon("signature")),
                        menuItem("11. Sensor response gas", tabName = "11_Effects", icon = icon("signature")),
                        menuItem("12. Sensor deviations", tabName = "12_Effects", icon = icon("align-right")),
                        menuItem("13. General", tabName = "13_Effects", icon = icon("linode")),
                        menuItem("14. Modelling", tabName = "14_Effects", icon = icon("bezier-curve")),
                        menuItem("15. PCA", tabName = "15_Effects", icon = icon("sort-amount-up")),
                        menuItem("16. Hydrogen", tabName = "16_Effects", icon = icon("tint"))
                        )),
        dashboardBody(
                      #shinyDashboardThemes(theme = "grey_dark"),
  
tabItems(

(...)

)))

server <- function(input, output){ 

(...)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)

```
````

Comment: Can you just resize it with `CTRL +` as you would do with any other webpage?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but this is more like a zoom function?

Comment: It would be much easier for somebody to help if this were reproducible. Can you demonstrate this with a general (simple/small) shiny app with source?

Comment: Indeed, I will add this later.

Comment: Hi, I added it now. I was focused more on the content recently, sorry.

Comment: Is there a reason why the app runs over a markdown file. Put the script into a normal .R file. You also defined a window_height in your script, which does not appear in the example...

Comment: I thought that is necessary. Will have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: I removed it but I got an error that window_height is missing. Nevertheless, when I add it in again (which means I basically didn't change anything), it works now..